How can I able to exclude 'Category' and 'Tag' slug from the URL in Wordpress without reloading to that new site?
in functions.php, I wrote this code:
function remove_category($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && ($query->is_category() || $query->is_tag())) {
        $category = get_queried_object();

        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        $query->set('category_name', $category->slug);

        $category_id = $category->term_id;
        $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);

        $url = $category_link;
        $arr = parse_url($url);
        $path = $arr['path'];
        $str_to_arr = explode('/', $path);
        $archive = $str_to_arr[2];
        $new_url = str_replace('/' . $archive, '', $url);
        echo "New URL: {$new_url}";
    }   
    return $new_url;
}

The code actually filters out category or tags based on the custom theme I am working on.
Now I have tried applying 'site-url' filter hook, but the site breaks. How can I able to achieve this?
